# css flexbox, variable height top and bottom with constraints

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container with a top and bottom.  I want the top to be dynamic height, but constrained to 60% of the height of the parent.  I want to bottom to take up all remaining height, even if empty.

Is css flex appropriate for this?

I've been trying variants around this

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
.bottom {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

but without much success.

https://jsfiddle.net/2gvL2dk8/

Edit, with this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/2gvL2dk8/3/

the top is not growing to the max 60% height, but the bottom is taking all remaining height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.  Not specifying flex on the top element allows it to grow and shrink normally, and keep a flex setting on the bottom makes that element use all the height.  Would delete the question but this might help people in the future.

```
.top {
    max-height: 60%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
.bottom {
    flex: 1 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
```